# How can I speed up call forwarding on Twilio? - Django

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I just implemented call forwarding based on the following Twilio tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-tracking-python-django

The call forwarding works, however there are about 3 seconds of "static sounds" before the phone that is dialing the number starts hearing the phone ringer.

Why is there such a delay in forwarding the call, how can this be resolved for a production level application? Calls are made over US phone networks, so did not expect delay issues.

This is the function implementing the forwarding:

```
# views.py
# View used by Twilio API to connect callers to the right forwarding
# number for that lead source
@csrf_exempt
def forward_call(request):
    """Connects an incoming call to the correct forwarding number"""

    r = VoiceResponse()
    r.dial('+12324567891')

    return HttpResponse(r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It appears that you are both reading data from and then saving data to a database before you respond with the TwiML to tell Twilio to forward the call. To get the quickest forwarding you should return TwiML as quick as you can.

Perhaps you can test the same forwarding without hitting the database and see if there is a difference. If there is, then I can see you need to read the database to get the number to forward to, but perhaps you could set up the saving of a new Lead to be done in a background job rather than block the response with it.

Another thing to try is to [set answerOnBridge="true" on your](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#answeronbridge) .

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I have removed the queries to the database, per your suggestion to see if it would speed up the call forwarding, it does not. See my updated question, for new function I tested with. There is still 3 seconds of "static sounds" before the phone that is dialing the number starts hearing the phone ringer.

Comment: Ok, another thing to try is to set [`answerOnBridge="true"` on your `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#answeronbridge). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: When I added answer_on_bridge=True on the dial, the ringer starts ringing immediately for the dialer, which is a better experience. However, there is still a delay , on the call ringing for the receiver's phone relative to a direct call. Is this expected? Anything further that can be done to fix it?

Comment: This isn't a direct call though, it goes through Twilio and has this intermediary step of finding out who to call. However, I assume your caller and callee won't be in the same room, so the experience for both would be no different to a direct call.

Comment: issue is the caller receives a 3+ second delay before phone even starts ringing for the callee. So it may be the case they hear 5+ rings before the callee gets a chance to pick up.

Comment: Like I said, this isn't a direct call, so it's not going to happen as fast as that. Instead, your initial caller is making a connection to Twilio, which makes a connection to your server to look up what to do, then Twilio needs to take that information and then make a connection out to the you are calling. There are more steps to this process so it will take longer. The call may ring for a bit longer, but your caller is unlikely to notice as they don't know what is happening on the other end.

Comment: Got it. I'm testing in local environment with ngrok. Do you expect the "speed" of my heroku servers to have a great impact on this latency?

Comment: Actually, if you use the default Heroku AWS region, then your server will be physically close to the Twilio servers and likely work quicker than your development version. I assume these are paid for Heroku dynos, free ones will sleep and definitely make things slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery and register forward call task with delay